# hide/show textarea via checkboxes with same classes for different sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Well, I have a form of interest and when I select an option from select list (e.g cars, motors) it gives me content relating to option.

Here is the test page -> [Here](http://anatolia-asfalisi.gr/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=prosfora)

I also have created checkboxes for each section (from above instance) and I want when I check a specific checkbox (.other) to display a text box for details (.textbox) and when I uncheck it to get hidden by default. I gave to this specific checkbox and each textarea the same class for each section. For checkbox -> .other and for textarea -> .textbox

This is the code (of checkboxes) for each section:

Cars

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
   <li><label for="thrausi"><input type="checkbox" name="thrausi" id="thrausi">text</label></li>
   <li><label for="odiki-car"><input type="checkbox" name="odiki-car" id="odiki-car"text</label></li>
   <li><label for="nomiki"><input type="checkbox" name="nomiki" id="nomiki">text</label></li>
   <li><label for="other-car"><input type="checkbox" class="other">**Other details**</label></li>
</ul>
<textarea class="textbox" name="other" style="display:none; width: 255px;" placeholder="text"></textarea>
```

Motors

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
   <li><label for="odiki-moto"><input type="checkbox" name="odiki-moto" id="odiki-moto">text</label></li>
   <li><label for="other"><input type="checkbox" class="other">**Other details**</label></li>
  </ul>
<textarea class="textbox" name="other" style="display:none; width: 255px;" placeholder="text"></textarea>
```

And I tried this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
var elem = document.getElementByClassName('textbox'),
    checkBox = document.getElementByClassName('other');
checkBox.checked = false;
checkBox.onchange = function() {
    elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
checkBox.onchange();
}
</script>
```

But I do something wrong. 
What do you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: onchange??? Checkboxes should work for 'onclick'

Comment: use document.getElementsByClassName('textbox')[0] and document.getElementsByClassName('other')[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the DEMO [[Click Here]](http://jsfiddle.net/0ud20e0f/)

As on the selection of **check box** with class **other** you want to show the corresponding **textarea**

you can use the following code snippet for the resolution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".other").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".textbox").show();
            else
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".textbox").hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Mayank thanks for your help. Thanks also everyone else who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
<script>
    $(function(){   
        $(".other").click(function(){
            if((this).is(":checked")==true)
            {
                $(".textbox").show();
            }
            else
               $(".textbox").hide();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tuned your code a bit

**jQuery Code:**

```
  $('.other').removeAttr('checked');
  $('.other').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest("div.par").find('.textbox').toggle();
  });
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/1y47bxfh/4/

*Note: when your using jquery lib in your code, make sure you use it, dont use raw js code.as the tagline itself suggests `write less do more`.*

Happy Coding :)